# Java cannot refer to a non-final variable

Tags: java, variables

```
for (int i=0; i<pages; i++) {
        ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
             ...

        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                showpage(i);
                }


            }
        });

        FLall.addView(img);
    }
```

how can i do this in java? I get always **"Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method"**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before the `setOnClickListener` call:

```
final int thisIndex = i;
```

And then refer to `thisIndex` in the handler.

Comment: Beat me to it. I'd just finished typing exactly this, but using i2 for the variable.

Answer (score 9):

Though you can create a junk variable and mark it `final` I actually prefer just passing this value through a constructor.  It's a little less concise, but if you decide to move your anonymous inner class at some point, it's a whole lot more maintainable.

```
for (int i=0; i<pages; i++) {
    ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
    ...

    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(i) {
        private int ind;
        public OnClickListener(int ind){
            super();
            this.ind = ind;
        }
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showpage(ind);
        }
    });

    FLall.addView(img);
}
```

Comment: I think OnClickListener would already have to have a constructor that accepts the argument.  (Feasible if it is not third-party or not a Java built-in but otherwise not feasible).  When I tried this, there was a complaint that no such constructor exists and the constructor you are providing for the anonymous implementation will also cause an error.